# Where is my software installed in Linux?

Tags: linux, matlab

I use `whereis matlab` and find:
`/usr/local/bin/matlab`
, which is a very long bash file.

How can I find where matlab is installed, I mean, its installed folder.

EDIT:

I used the following method:
open matlab and use edit svds.m to open the svds.m file and the editor shows the folder:)

Comment: What is your linux distribution? Is matlab installed as rpm package or from source/tarball?

Answer (score 14):

Try

```
locate MATLAB
```

The binary file is spelled with all-caps.  In my system, the MATLAB executable is installed in `/usr/local/matlab/r2009b/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB` (which is a slightly weird place).  The matlab root would then be `/usr/local/matlab/r2009b`

Of course, normally you do run matlab using the long shell script...

Comment: Note: you might need to run `sudo updatedb` once before running `locate` (it's possible it won't find nearly as much otherwise).

Comment: I first needed to install ti: `sudo apt install mlocate`, than the `locate MATLAB` worked.

Answer (score 3):

I did

```
cat `which matlab` | grep matlab
```

with output

```
exec /usr/local/bin/matlab64 -r maxNumCompThreads=4 $*
    echo "   qsub -I -V -l nodes=1,matlab=1"
            exec /usr/local/bin/matlab64 $*
            exec /usr/local/bin/matlab32 $*
```

Then

```
$ ls -ld /usr/local/bin/matlab64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 May  4 12:08 /usr/local/bin/matlab64 -> /usr/local/matlab64/bin/matlab
$ ls -ld /usr/local/bin/matlab32
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 May  4 12:08 /usr/local/bin/matlab32 -> /usr/local/matlab/bin/matlab
$ ls -ld /usr/local/matlab64 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 May  4 12:01 /usr/local/matlab64 -> /usr/local/matlab_2010a-64/
$ ls -ld /usr/local/matlab 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 May  4 12:01 /usr/local/matlab -> /usr/local/matlab_2010a
```

**EDIT**:
The better way is to do it from matlab command line with [matlabroot](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/matlabroot.html).

```
>> matlabroot

ans =

/usr/local/matlab_2010a-64
```

Comment: Useless use of `cat`: `grep matlab $(which matlab)`

Answer (score 1):

On RPM based distributions you can use

```
rpm -ql <package_name>
```

It will show you all files from the package

```
# rpm -ql wget
/etc/wgetrc
/usr/bin/wget
/usr/share/doc/wget-1.10.2
/usr/share/doc/wget-1.10.2/AUTHORS
....
```

If you're not sure how the package is called, you may use something like `rpm -qa | grep -i matlab` to find its name

Answer (score 0):

Tthe locations would depend (as Dmitry has suggested) on how you installed the packages. Usually, installation from source would dump the binaries and related files in `/usr/local`. For details on where standard distributions (like Debian and others put files), consult the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

Answer (score 0):

Your package manager might tell you.
YAST in opensuse has a files tab, which shows all the files and location they get installed to. I can't speak for other distros.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux environment, you can run the following code to get MATLAB paths

```
matlab -e | sed -n 's/MATLAB=//p'
```

where `matlab -e` will output a lot of information to run MATLAB. So we need to pipe them to `sed -n 's/MATLAB=//p'` to only select the MATLAB root. I use this in my Makefile document to find the path to `mex` compiler without start MATLAB. It is very quick command. Here is what I used in my Makefile document just for convenience:

```
MATLAB = $(shell matlab -e | sed -n 's/MATLAB=//p')
MEX = $(MATLAB)/bin/mex
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the official answer of MathWorks (See [Where is MATLAB installed on my machine?](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/175704)) it is located in - `\usr\local\MATLAB\Rxxxxx` where `xxxxx` stands for the version. For instance `R2019a` for the version released in March 2019.